# how to Avoid warning message on click of custom URL

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc

I have register a custom URL in my system as described in the bellow link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx

when i send a mail to my email. i opened the mail in outlook email client and clicked on the link then it displayed warning message

> Microsoft office had identified a potential security
>   concern.Hyperlinks can be harmful to your computer and data. To
>   protect your computer, click only those hyperlinks from trusted
>   sources.

Is there any way to disable the warning message?

If i digitally sign the email will that warning message comes?

If i sign the binary will that warning message comes?

Answer (score 0):

That is just a security warning in Outlook itself, it has nothing to do with your custom URL.

[How to enable or disable hyperlink warning messages in 2007 Office programs and in Office 2010 programs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925757)